# c++ virtual destructor - memory leak

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve the following problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

class Talker
{
public:
    virtual void SaySomething() = 0;
};

class SoundProducer
{
protected:
    string soundName;
public:
    SoundProducer(string nameOfSound)
    {
        this->soundName = nameOfSound;      
    }

    virtual void MakeSound() = 0;

    string GetSoundName()
    {
        return this->soundName;
    }
};

class Uppgift1 : public Talker
{
private:
    SoundProducer* t;

public:
    Uppgift1(){};

    void SetSoundProducer(SoundProducer* _soundProducer)
    {
        t = _soundProducer;
    }

    void SaySomething()
    {
        t->MakeSound();
    }

    virtual ~Uppgift1()
    {
        delete t;
    }
};

class Whisperer : public SoundProducer
{
public:
    Whisperer() : SoundProducer("Whisper"){}

    virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        cout << soundName << ": Ssch,hush,hush" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Whisperer()
    {
        cout << "Whisperer destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

class Shouter : public SoundProducer
{
public:
    Shouter() : SoundProducer("Shout"){}

    virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        cout << soundName << ": WOW YEEEH!!" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Shouter()
    {
        cout << "Shouter destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Uppgift1 uppg1;
    uppg1.SetSoundProducer(new Whisperer);
    uppg1.SaySomething();
    uppg1.SetSoundProducer(new Shouter);
    uppg1.SaySomething();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having is memory leaks and im trying to figure out how to delete a pointer to a class when it runs out of scope.

As for now shout and whisperer don't get deleted which results in memory-leak.

Looks like the only way to do it is by making the SoundProducer class inherit uppgift1 class and making the destructor virtual, am I right? I'm kind of tired so sorry if i confuse you as well :)

Comment: `SetSoundProducer` simply reassigns what `Uppgift1::t` points to without considering what it used to point to. That's a definite memory leak. You should use a `std::unique_ptr` and call its `reset()` method. Also, `SoundProducer` needs a virtual destructor because otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: In addition to all that's been said, you're calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` before `uppg1` goes out of scope and has its destructor called. Put the stuff before it in a `{}` block, or you'll see memory leaks even when the code is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set soundproducer twice but UppGift can only hold one....Hence, the destructor of Shouter gets called since it is the last element added and destructor of whisperer never gets called, since you already set  it again to shouter.

Before:

```
Uppgift1 uppg1;
uppg1.SetSoundProducer(new Whisperer);
uppg1.SaySomething();
uppg1.SetSoundProducer(new Shouter);
```

You make a call on set twice but only one can be held.

```
SoundProducer* t;
```

After:

Maintain a list/vector of them if you have multiple SoundProducers to be added.

```
vector<SoundProducer*> _list;

    virtual ~Uppgift1()
    {
    //    delete t;
     std::vector< SoundProducer*>::iterator it = _list.begin();
    //delete *it;
  for ( ; it != _list.end(); it++ ) 
  {
            delete *it;

  }
_list.clear();
```

In Inheritance tree, the base class destructor should be virtual if you are trying to delete the derived class instance through a base pointer.That way the derived class destructor gets called when you do a delete on a base class pointer pointing to  derived class instance
I have edited the code now.It works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
//#include <crtdbg.h>

class Talker
{
public:
    virtual void SaySomething() = 0;
    virtual ~Talker(){cout<<"Talker Destructor"<<endl;}
};

class SoundProducer
{
protected:
    string soundName;
public:
    SoundProducer(string nameOfSound)
    {
        this->soundName = nameOfSound;      
    }

    virtual void MakeSound() = 0;

    string GetSoundName()
    {
        return this->soundName;
    }
    virtual ~SoundProducer(){cout<<"SoundProducer Detructor"<<endl;}
};

class Uppgift1 : public Talker
{
private:
    SoundProducer* t;
     vector<SoundProducer*> _list;
public:
    Uppgift1(){};

    void SetSoundProducer(SoundProducer* _soundProducer)
    {
        if(_soundProducer)
      {  cout<<"pushing into list"<<endl;
        _list.push_back(_soundProducer);
      }
     //   t = _soundProducer;
    }

    void SaySomething()
    {
       // t->MakeSound();
    }

    virtual ~Uppgift1()
    {
    //    delete t;
     std::vector< SoundProducer*>::iterator it = _list.begin();
    //delete *it;
  for ( ; it != _list.end(); it++ ) 
  {
            delete *it;

  }
_list.clear(); 


    }


};

class Whisperer : public SoundProducer
{
public:
    Whisperer() : SoundProducer("Whisper"){}

    virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        cout << soundName << ": Ssch,hush,hush" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Whisperer()
    {
        cout << "Whisperer destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

class Shouter : public SoundProducer
{
public:
    Shouter() : SoundProducer("Shout"){}

    virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        cout << soundName << ": WOW YEEEH!!" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Shouter()
    {
        cout << "Shouter destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Uppgift1 uppg1;
    SoundProducer* ptr=new Whisperer;
    uppg1.SetSoundProducer(dynamic_cast<SoundProducer*>(ptr));
    uppg1.SaySomething();
    uppg1.SetSoundProducer(new Shouter);
    uppg1.SaySomething();

 //   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Whisper doesn't get deleted. You can try it out yourself. Remember that SoundProducer is not inheriting anything.

Comment: look at the answer now....If you really wnat multiple Soundproducers then maintain a list of them in uppGift

Comment: Thank you but I did know that i could use a vector and delete all the created objects that way but wanted to know if its possible to do this by making Soundproducer inherit Uppgift1 class? Simply put, is there another way?

Comment: the code above works after youhave converted base class destructor to virtual...But the problem here is, you have only one pointer and you first point it to one instance, and then , you set it to another instance before deleting the first instance....it's explained in the answer....hence, maintain different pointers to different instances .....read the answer carefully

Answer (score 0):

`Uppgift1.SetSoundProducer` takes ownership of the passed `SoundProducer`, aside from not doing quite that:

1. It will `delete` the last one set on destruction.
2. But **it won't `delete` the previous one** on setting a new one.

Also, the **member-pointer is left indeterminate** when creating a variable of type `Uppgift1`, and you generally ignored the "rule-of-three", which says you really have to define copy-ctor and copy-assignment in addition to the custom dtor.

Next, let's look at how the members pointe is deleted:

```
delete t;
```

As the type of `t` does not have a virtual dtor, it must point to an object of the fully-derived type the pointer declares.
Unfortunately, you are setting a `Shouter` last, which is a derived class, and thus have UB.

You should take a look at smart-pointers, especially `std::unique_ptr`, and for some occasions `std::shared_ptr`.